# How do I run code on DOM ready in Greasemonkey 4?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

With the update to Firefox 57 and Greasemonkey 4 a number of my userscripts broke. In some scripts I used:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doStuff, false);
```

This no longer works in Greasemonkey. What is the proper way to add an `DOMContentLoaded` event now?

P.S. I checked that at the time of registering the event, DOM is still not ready.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem after GreaseMonkey upgraded to version 4, but I used

```
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // …
});
```

instead.

When trying to fix my user-scripts, I initially commented out that wrapper and put a

```
// @run-at document-end
```

in the [metadata block](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block). This way, I ensured that the DOM was ready and the code that was originally inside the `DOMContentLoaded` wrapper executed correctly.

This worked, however, for two of my user-scripts I actually needed to run JavaScript, before any page script had run *and* execute other code when the DOM was ready. It turns out, that now you *need* to put

```
// @run-at document-start
```

in the metadata block in order for the `DOMContentLoaded` wrapper to work on your `window` (or `document`).

In previous versions of GreaseMonkey I could just omit this and it would run fine.

However, according to the [GreaseSpot Wiki](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at), `document-start` is not guaranteed to work in GreaseMonkey 4.0, perhaps due to asynchrounous execution or missing features in the WebExtensions rewrite of the add-on.

Also, `document.readyState` will be `"loading"` with `document-start`, but `"interactive"` with `document-end` or no `// @run-at` at all.

Comment: Interesting! For me, the trick was to just remove the addEventListener function althogether. I copy-pasted what was inside the anonymous function, outside. I also have no @run-at set. I had to use the addEventListener function on previous versions of Greasemonkey, but now it works with everything omitted.

Comment: @Yani2000 That worked for me as well, but only for some scripts, where I didn’t need to distinguish between running code before the DOM has loaded and after.

Comment: Someone just upvoted this answer. Is it still up to date? I probably need to test this again.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know what is the recommended way of running code on DOM ready in Greasemonkey 4, but after changing:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doStuff, false);
```

to:

```
window.addEventListener('load', doStuff, false);
```

my script works again. I just started testing other methods based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701), since I noticed that my jQuery based user scripts are still working (at least the DOM ready part does).

This answer is kind of obvious, but at the time of writing the question, I wasn't sure if I was keeping up with the changes in Greasemonkey (reading about all the async stuff) and I expected `DOMContentLoaded` to just work.

Comment: Did you try `@run-at document-end`?

Comment: @peterh I did it and, unfortunately, it is not working anymore :(

Comment: @gal007 I switched to another FF userscript extension, I forgot its name, but it works much better.