# Greasemonkey script does not work inside a popup

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

I've written a simple greasemonkey script to click the next button on a popup module presentation window when I hit the right-arrow-key.

I haven't been able to find much information about this online. The code seems to work if the window is not a popup, otherwise it just prints the console.log outside of the function and never gets to the inside of the function myEventHandler. I think the problem seems to be with window.addEventListener or that the events are simply not being fired.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Back/Next with Arrow Keys
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @run-at          document-end
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener("keypress", myEventHandler, false);

console.log('Outside function');
function myEventHandler(e) {
    console.log('fired EventHandler');
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        console.log(e, keyCode, e.which)
        if (keyCode === 39) {
      console.log('Right arrow key pressed!');
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn cs-button inflexible  slide-control-button-next slide-lockable");
        x[0].click();
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll be happy to provide any more information that's needed.

Comment: Maybe this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481141/how-do-i-run-code-on-dom-ready-in-greasemonkey-4

Comment: You need to provide a [mre].  Or at the very least, the full script (if it is short) and a link to the target page.

Comment: @mari Thanks, I tried using DOMContentLoaded, but it didn't work.

Comment: @BrockAdams The website isn't accessible outside my company's network. It's basically one of those websites where you open a learning module and it opens in a new popup window. And I've updated the question with the full script.

Comment: That's where the [mre] comes in.  You're not paying us enough to troubleshoot blind, via text exchanges.  ... So, verify that you see a NEW `Outside function` appear in the console when the popup appears (and not before), but the `fired EventHandler` message never appears and niether do any errors?  Also, try the script in Tampermonkey.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to automate your mandatory corporate training? Does it log 'outside function' or 'fired EventHandler'?

Comment: @BrockAdams I know, and I apologize, but I am extremely grateful for everyone's help here. I confirm that I see a NEW `Outside function` appear in the console when the popup appears, and yes the `fired EventHandler` message never shows up and neither do any errors. I'm going to try the script in Tampermonkey and get back to you.

Comment: @Jeff It only logs 'outside function' and no not at all, the learning modules don't let you navigate using the arrow keys, so I'm creating a GM script for everyone to use ^_^ If I had to simply automate it, I'd have used PyAutoGUI or something haha

Comment: Check in the code for what launches the pop-up.  If they use `window.open` and it's assigned a variable, you can do `<variablename>.addEventListener` and `<variablename>.document.getElementByClassName`  that *should* allow you to work the pop-up DOM.  You'd have to run it everytime the pop-up is launched though.  I believe you can re-write the function that launches the pop-up in greasemonkey and it's override the function on the webpage.

Comment: @Jeff The button has a `data-ctl-options='{"actiontype":"ACTION","value":"Click","sourceID":"_zl3lk_a"}'`

Comment: Well, if the script works fine in a regular tab, and works as described (in the comments) in a popup, then some other element may be destructively intercepting keypresses.  This *might* be because the window is smaller and/or the focus has shifted.  So: (1) listen for `keydown` not keypress. (2) Check and set the focus if needed. (3) Check for conflicting event handlers. (4) Set `useCapture` to true. (5) Change which element has your listener attached.

Comment: @BrockAdams I tested the same script in TamperMonkey and it works just fine. This might just be something to do with Greasemonkey and popups perhaps. I will be updating the Usage instructions to use TamperMonkey instead of Greasemonkey in the Wiki where I have it up. We could still try to figure out why it doesn't work with Greasemonkey if you guys want to. :)

Comment: @BrockAdams I'll try your suggestions to make it work with Greasemonkey as well and get back to you. Thanks again for your help. :)